# iOS App icon turns black in only iPhone 13pro and max. Does any one having that issue or any solution?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

We using the same code and there is no any special code required for setting up app icon for iOS apps.

I found strange issue which the app icon show black in app store where that appear correct in the devices up to iPhone 13.

That appears black only from iPhone 13 and 13 max pro.

[image]

- Off course we checked all the size and added all the size.
- We not added app icon at appstore connect as now that grab from build.
- We also not setting transparent app icon we are sure about it.

I am not sure that bugs from Apple side or is there anything required to setting up. Let me know if you have same issue and having any solution for it.

Thank you very much

Comment: It seems Apple's side issue only though is it showing the proper icon at the iTunes developer portal?

Comment: Yes that show correct at developer portal as well as and the joking part is that even show in iPhone 13 that issue only in 13pro and max

Comment: Got it... may be some glitch at Apple !

Comment: 1 more thing you could check is, try with TestFlight and see what icon you see on pro n max

Comment: @Maulik thats good idea in case found the solution will post an answer thanks maulik